# Можно ли после удаления всех строк добавлять новые с id=1?

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть БД SQLite.

Методом `.delete()` я сношу все строки. После чего я добавляю новую строку, но у нее значение в поле `_id` равно не 1, а старому максимальному значению +1. Это, я так понимаю, из-за `autoincrement` у `_id`, которое PK.

Можно ли как-то удалить строку вместе с ее id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте ресетнуть sequence для таблицы:

```
DELETE FROM your_table;    
DELETE SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='your_table';
```

Или:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'your_table'
```

Answer (score -3):

Прикол весь в том, что данные из базы не удаляются, а только лишь затираются, поэтому Id счёт происходит не с 0, а продолжается с последнего добавленного, даже удалённого